# How does pow(a, b, c) work for this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I was attempting the question [Last digit of a large number](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5511b2f550906349a70004e1/python) at codewars.

After solving it myself, I saw a very simple solution:

```
def last_digit(n1, n2):
    return pow( n1, n2, 10 )
```

I am very confused about how this above code works. I tried to see similar problems on other sites, but no luck.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What is unclear? Do you know what modulo is?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  In particular, we expect you to research the issue before posting here.  `pow` is documented quite well.

Comment: @Prune: He's not confused about pow, he's confused about why a\*\*b mod 10 gives the last digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last digit of a number you do n % 10. The syntax for pow is the following:
pow(base, exponent, modulus). In your case, if modulus is 10, then pow will return you the last digit of base^exponent.